# Website Components Don't Resize when Viewing Horizontally on Mobile

Tags: html, css

I've created a website that works perfectly when viewed on desktop. When I view it vertically on a mobile phone, everything fits on screen, just like on a desktop. However, when I tilt the phone and view the website horizontally, everything scales wrong, even after refreshing.

For the size of containers, images, etc. I've used vw and vh.

When I view the website horizontally, the width and height effectively switch values... except the components are still the same size as they were in portrait mode.

Can anyone tell me how I can bind the sizes of components to the width/height or the screen?

Comment: You should look into responsive web design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have could appear out of the aspect ratio that changes when you tilt your phone.

If you use vw and vh units - keep in mind, that a container in vertical hold has ~ twice the total height if its in horizontal position.

I.E.: A samsung galaxy s5 has 360px on short and 640px on its long side.

You have several options to solve your problem, just two of them but in my opinion the most powerful are the following.

Take a look on the flexbox system - it's really simple and easy to use, especially for responsive designs!
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

With media querys you can set different attributes and values for different display/window sizes. 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp